# adb push fails with Invalid argument

Tags: android, adb

Hi I what to push an APK Expansion file to my phone so I am executing:

`C:\Users\dogface\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools>adb.exe push c
:\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb  /mnt/sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.Audiobook\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb`

But that fails with this error:

`failed to copy 'c:\main.1.com.redcricket.Audiobook.obb' to '/mnt/
sdcard/Android/obb/com.redcricket.Audiobook\main.1.com.redcricket
.Audiobook.obb': Invalid argument`

So what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: i doubt whether this directory is there? "com.redcricket.Audiobook\main.1.com.redcricket .Audiobook.obb" on sdcard. pls check once.

Comment: Are the blanks in the file name a copy paste problem or are they real? Also, don't use `\\` as a file separator on Android.

Answer (score 2):

please try

In C drive create any folder and then put apk in that and try it. dont create main.1. plese change package name and then try again.

for eg:

```
 adb push foo.txt /sdcard/foo.txt
```